# Async instance method

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

## Async instance method

I want to add an instance method to my model **Reservation**, this instance method will perform a query on the relations model and execute some calculations on it. However, return a value asynchronously ain't possible.

I have a solution which returns a Promise, but that really ain't feasible when having multiple instance methods to return as a json object.

#### Controller

```
// controllers/ParkingController
reservationsCount: function(req, res, next){
  Parking.find('5751401d54f4ca110020c15b').exec(function(err, parking) {
    console.log(parking.reservationsCount())
    res.json({});
  });
}
```

#### Model

```
// models/Parking
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: { type: 'string'},
    reservations: {
      collection: "reservation",
      via: "parking",
    },
    getReservationsCount: function(cb) {
      return Parking.findOne(this.id).populate('reservations').exec(function(err, result){
        cb(result.reservations.length);
      });
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

**Model**

```
getReservationsCount: function() { // no callback since we use Promises
  return Parking.findOne(this.id)
  .populate('reservations')
  .then(function(parking){
    return parking.reservations.length;
  });
},
```

**Controller**

```
reservationsCount: function(req, res){ // next is useless in sails
  Parking.findOne('5751401d54f4ca110020c15b') // findOne to get one object
  .then(function(parking) {
    return parking.getReservationsCount(); // getReservationsCount returns a Promise
  })
 .then(function(reservationsCount){
    return res.json({reservationsCount});
  })
 .catch(function(err){
   sails.log.error(err);
   // handle error
 });
}
```